# Android Navigation Drawer Icons' Color

Tags: android, material-design, android-drawable, navigation-drawer

Is there a way to change navigations drawer icons' color? What I mean is that even I use a png that includes more than one color, the icon that drawn in the app has one color and  I think default color is grey, can I make it colorful?

For example:

[image: My png file that I want to use for icon]

This is my png file that I want to use for icon but when I use it as navigation drawer items' icon it drawn like that:

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific. This question doesn't make a whole lot of sense as it is. Perhaps post an image showing your issue.

Comment: I think my question is clear, does the navigation drawer icons' be colorful or they should have single color?

Comment: if you want help, when someone asks for more information or says that you are unclear, you probably shouldn't argue... unless you don't want help.

Comment: Unclear what you want to change. Adding screenshots is better when you feel that the question is ambiguous. Below I've provided 2 methods, please check if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set

> navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

in your onCreate()

using this you can set different color icon of navigationdrawer.

Comment: This worked great, thanks!!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

**Changing icons INSIDE navigation drawer:**

You can easily specify color in your navigation view **XML**:

Just add the desired color in itemIconTint property.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    app:itemIconTint="#000000" //choose your color here.....
    ...
/>
```

**Changing navigation drawer icon color** 
(clicking which the drawer opens):

Set the theme:

```
<style name="MyDrawerArrowTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And add this custom theme in your application theme:

```
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowTheme</item>
```